# MySQL query return undefined - NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have this code and i don't know why it return "undefined" i already read some docs about async and await but it is not very clear to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
const createNewBinnacleName = () => {

    const dataBase = mysql.createConnection({
        user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        password: "",
        multipleStatements: true
    })

    dataBase.query("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'bit_%';", (error, result) => {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
        if(result)
        {
            const splitName = result[result.length - 1].Database.split("_")
            let date = new Date();
            let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            let year = date.getFullYear();
            const binnacleNumber = parseInt(splitName[3], 10) + 1;
            const binnacleName = "bit_" + month + "_" + year + "_" + (binnacleNumber).pad(3);
            
            return binnacleName;
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT:

Updated according to the answer given, now I have this error: "Promise {  }"

```
const createNewBinnacleName = async () => {

    const dataBase = mysql.createConnection({
        user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        password: "",
        multipleStatements: true
    })

    try
    {
        const result = await dataBase.query("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'bit_%';");

        if(result)
        {
            const splitName = result[result.length - 1].Database.split("_")
            let date = new Date();
            let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            let year = date.getFullYear();
            const binnacleNumber = parseInt(splitName[3], 10) + 1;
            const binnacleName = "bit_" + month + "_" + year + "_" + (binnacleNumber).pad(3);
            
            return binnacleName;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        console.log("error");
    } 
}
async function run() {
    const test = await createNewBinnacleName();
}
console.log(run());
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

try using async-await  something like this

```
const dataBase = mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    password: "",
    multipleStatements: true
})

const createNewBinnacleName = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dataBase.query("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS `Database` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'bit_%';", (error, result) => {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
            if(result)
            {
                const splitName = result[result.length - 1].Database.split("_")
                let date = new Date();
                let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                let year = date.getFullYear();
                const binnacleNumber = parseInt(splitName[3], 10) + 1;
                const binnacleName = "bit_" + month + "_" + year + "_" + (binnacleNumber).pad(3);
                
                 resolve(binnacleName)
            }
        })
    });
}
```

then call the function

```
async function getBinnacleName() { 
   const binnacleName = await createNewBinnacleName(); 
   return binnacleName;
} 

getBinnacleName();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I made the necessary changes and I've got this "Promise { <pending> }", don't know why the promise isn't fulfilling. Any other ideas?

Comment: are u using await to call createNewBinnacleName function ?

try something like this in calling function

async function run() {
  const binnacleName = await createNewBinnacleName();
  console.log(binnacleName); // will print your data
}

run();

Comment: Yes, I'm using it and it keeps waiting for the promise response.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the delay. I have updated my post.

Comment: This worked 100% for me, thank you very mucht searched like at least 1 hour for this fix, it kept returnign undefined or promise {} nut now it renders my EJS page with the data which was retrieved asycnly thank you!